# How to change fullcalendar layout to column headers as a time slots

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I want to change column headers to time slots in react fullcalendar. Is there any way to show other week as below. I want to do it somehow. Is there any solution to this fullcalendar or do I have to do it by creating another fullcalendar?

[image: column headers like "Sun 10/1"]

Comment: You mean you want to show time across the top and days along the side? No, fullCalendar does not offer that currently, but you could ask them to develop it, and/or contribute towards that effort yourself - see https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features